# isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

How to calculate the isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^n$? And show that $G$ is generated by rotations, reflections and translations?

Can someone help me?

Comment: By a rotation on $\Bbb R^n$, doyou mean an element of $SO(n)$ fixing the points of a subspace of dimension $n-2$?

Comment: Yeah. 
Would you help me?

Comment: The user **Isadora Suhadolnick** performed an edit of this post that deviated significantly from the original question. Sadly, the edit reviewers have been superficial and approved it, so I rolled it back. Isadora, please do not hijack other peoples' posts; instead, ask a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought he wanted this.

Comment: Why two questions? See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3966025

Comment: @Milou, can you please accept the answers that have been useful to you? We see that you asked 23 questions without accepting any answer. This is definitely not polite and you should at least try to follow the rules of this site.

Comment: @EroSennin I'm sorry. I did not know that. I will go accept the answers.

Comment: No problem, it is just a sign that basically helps other people to understand that you fine answers useful. Moreover it’s also a way to thank you answers you. You could do also for the other answers of the last weeks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a guideline:

1. Show that $f:\Bbb R^n \longrightarrow \Bbb R^n$ is an isometry if and only if for all translations $T:\Bbb R^n \longrightarrow \Bbb R^n$, $T\circ f$ is an isometry.
2. Show that if $f:\Bbb R^n \longrightarrow \Bbb R^n$ is an isometry with $f(0) = 0$, then $f$ is linear.
3. What can you say about linear isometries of $\Bbb R^n$? What do you know about these transformations and the matrices that represent them?

Comment: If I show (1) and (2) is the exercise over?

Comment: Step $(3)$ is part of it too.